# How to save the image as EmbeddedResource in WindowsPhone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I use the PhotoChooserTask() to load the Image in my WindowsPhone app.. Is there any way to change it as a EmbeddedResource ?

Comment: Embedded Resources are compiled into the assembly so I doubt this is possible. Why would you need to do this?

Comment: Yes.. I need to do this... is there any code for this ?

Comment: I was saying this was probably not possible, and asking why you would want to do it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

An embeddedresource is contained within a compiled, signed binary file. To do this would require you to modify the compiled code and then resign it with a trusted certificate.
As the security model for the platform means that only files signed as part of the marketplace certification process are trusted on the phone can be used means that this definitely isn't possible.

When you say "I need to do this" - why?
If you're obtaining a file from elsewhere (the web) there's no need to save it as an embeddedresource to be able to use it in your application.